# Why daughter class objects call member function of mother class?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to create a base class "process" with a method "execute()" that runs a task "work()" in thread. when i create a derived class "product" for example, and an object "p" with it, p.execute() runs "work()" of base class even if it is virtual. can any one tell me why?

here is my code:
1-for base class:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>


class process 
{ 

private:

        std::thread  *th;                
public: 
    virtual void work();
    virtual void execute();

    //Delete the copy constructor
    process(const process&) = delete;

    //Delete the Assignment opeartor
    process& operator=(const process&) = delete;

    // Parameterized Constructor
    process();

    // Move Constructor
    process(process && obj);

    //Move Assignment Operator
    process & operator=(process && obj);

    //Destructor
    ~process();

}; 

// Parameterized Constructor
process::process()
{
    th!=NULL;
}

// Move Constructor
process::process(process && obj) : th(std::move(obj.th))
{
    std::cout << "Move Constructor is called" << std::endl;
}

//Move Assignment Operator
process & process::operator=(process && obj)
{
    std::cout << "Move Assignment is called" << std::endl;
    if (th->joinable())
        th->join();
    th = std::move(obj.th);
    return *this;
}


// Destructor
process::~process()
{
    if(th!=NULL){
        if (th->joinable())
          th->join();
    }
}



void process::work() 
{ 
    printf("work of base class \n");
} 


void process::execute() 
{ 
    printf("execute of base class \n");
    th=new  std::thread(&process::work, this);
}
```

2-for derived class:

```
class product : public process 
{ 
public: 
    void work();
};


void product::work() {
    printf("work of product class\n");
}
```

3-main function:

```
int main()
{
    product p;
    p.execute();

    return 0;
}
```

i expected to get :

```
execute of base class 
work of product class
```

but i actually get:

```
execute of base class 
work of base class
```

Comment: Why do you feel the need to use dynamic polymorphism (virtual functions)?

Answer (score 7):

Your code has undefined behaviour, because you join in the wrong place.

Although your class correctly joins the thread on destruction, ensuring that the `process` is still alive for the duration of the thread, [*the derived sub-object is already dead by then*](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#order-dtors-for-members).

As a result, you may see `product::execute` be invoked, or `process::execute` be invoked, or cats pour out of your monitor and start typing their own program.

You need to join before *any* of the object is destroyed, either from within `main` or by adding this code also to the `product` destructor.

When making this change I get the expected results.

---

**tl;dr: the virtual call works fine, but your join is in the wrong place.**

---

Furthermore, you include `<iostream>` but never use it, you store (and move!) a pointer to a `std::thread` rather than simply having a `std::thread`, and your "parameterized constructor" takes no parameters (and has a useless `th!=NULL`, and does nothing).

Here's a quick fix for all of the above:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

class process 
{
private:
    std::thread th;

public:
    virtual void work();
    virtual void execute();
    void endExecution();

    ~process();
}; 

process::~process()
{
    // Just in case, but you don't want to rely on this!
    // See main() -- or do this also in ~product().
    endExecution();
}

void process::work() 
{ 
    std::cerr << "work of base class\n";
} 

void process::execute() 
{
    std::cerr << "execute of base class\n";
    th = std::thread(&process::work, this);
} 

void process::endExecution()
{
    if (th.joinable())
        th.join();
}

class product : public process 
{ 
public: 
    virtual void work() override;
};


void product::work() {
    std::cerr << "work of product class\n";
}

int main()
{
    product p;
    p.execute();
    p.endExecution();
}
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c28340fe035c4f8))

Better class designs should allow you to do this in a less error-prone way.